# The maximum column value of all tables

Tags: sql, oracle

It's possible to add to below script max value of one specific column (each have this column with the same name):

```
select 
  owner, 
  table_name, 
  round((num_rows*avg_row_len)/(1024*1024)) MB,
  num_rows "ROWS",
  last_analyzed
--max(data_for_each_column)
from all_tables 
where owner = 'OAP'
order by table_name asc
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result.

Comment: All_tab_columns table in Oracle can help u.

Comment: I need column that show me max value (of one column) for each table.

Comment: How do you know which column you want to get the data from in each table?

Comment: I have to check the same column for each table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all tables do have one common column, you can use a hack with XML to dynamically create a `select max()` for each table:

```
select owner, 
       table_name, 
       round((num_rows*avg_row_len)/(1024*1024)) MB,
       num_rows "ROWS",
       last_analyzed,
       dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('SELECT max(id) m FROM '||owner||'.'||table_name).extract('//text()').getnumberval() as max_id
from all_tables tbl
where owner = 'OAP'
  and exists (select 1 
              from all_tab_columns ac
              where ac.owner = tbl.owner
                and ac.table_name = tbl.table_name
                and ac.column_name = 'ID')
order by table_name asc;
```

You need to replace `max(id)` with the correct column name.

The query will fail if there is at least one table that does not have a column named `id` - it will not just "skip" that table. Using the `and exists (..)` condition will only use table that have a column named `ID`.

---

`dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype()` will run the passed SQL query and return a XML representation of the result set, something like:

```
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <M>42</M>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

The `extract('//text()')` simply extracts the (only) text value in the result which is `'42'` and `getnumberval()` will turn that into a real number.

Comment: It's possible to put where clause to skip columns without "id"?

Comment: @PNPTestovir: you can only exclude tables without such a column from the overall select . It's not possible to run the "dynamic select" only for those that do have such a column

Comment: How to do it (exclude tables without such a column from the overall select)?

Comment: @PNPTestovir: see my edit

Comment: It returns me error http://iv.pl/images/06903638524181381676.png

Comment: @PNPTestovir: then you must exclude columns of that type.